# FInd MAX after SUM WinSQL- Branch with highest qty for an item

Tags: sql, oracle

The following link is a close case, but this code didn't work, and I couldn't figure it out -> [using max() and sum()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916257/using-max-and-sum)

**Oracle info:**

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE 11.2.0.2.0 Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

I need to retrieve the Branch with the highest Back Orders for a specific item from 2 tables. For each item, there are different clients, so there are separate quantities back ordered per item per branch. I need to add all the quantities for item A and see which Branch has highest qty back ordered. Sum it and then MAX...

If I do:

```
SELECT BRANCH, ITEM, MAX(QTY) AS LEQTY
FROM
(

    SELECT BRANCH, ITEM, SUM(QTY) AS LEQTY
       FROM TABLE1
     GROUP BY BRANCH, ITEM
    UNION ALL
    SELECT BRANCH, ITEM, SUM(QTY) AS LEQTY
       FROM TABLE2
     GROUP BY BRANCH, ITEM
    )
    WHERE ITEM = 'XYZ'
    GROUP BY BRANCH, ITEM
```

I get:
(the QTYs are the sums per branch)

```
   BRANCH   ITEM    QTY
   ------   ----    ---
   BRANCH1  XYZ     3
   BRANCH2  XYZ     0
   BRANCH3  XYZ     4
   BRANCH4  XYZ     21
```

but I need :

```
BRANCH   ITEM    QTY
------   ----    ---
BRANCH4  XYZ     21
```

Also tried (using only 1 table for the sake of example):

```
SELECT BRANCH, ITEM, MAX(QTY)
FROM TABLE1
WHERE QTY = (SELECT SUM(QTY)
                FROM TABLE1
                WHERE ITEM = 'XYZ'
                )
  AND ITEM = 'XYZ'
GROUP BY BRANCH, ITEM
```

It gives me a line, but the wrong one.

And finally, I have come up with this:

```
SELECT A.BRANCH, A.ITEM, MAX(A.QTY) AS ITEM
FROM TABLE1 A, (SELECT BRANCH, ITEM, SUM(QTY) AS LEQTY
                           FROM TABLE1
                           GROUP BY BRANCH, ITEM) B
      WHERE A.BRANCH = B.BRANCH
      AND MAX(B.QTY)
GROUP BY A.BRANCH, A.ITEM
```

Which gives me an ORA-00934

What am I missing?

THanks

Comment: Why would you want a count of 21 rather than 25?

Comment: Just a guess, but most RDBMS I have dealt with don't allow aggregate functions referenced in WHERE clauses. _(Which corresponds with the error description that comes up on google of "Group function not allowed here")_

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have the same item sold to different clients in different branches. For each branch, for the same item, there will be different quantities to sum up. For Branch4, the total is 21 items from 3 clients (client A back order =1 item, Client B = 11 items, and client C = 9 items). I want to know the sum of all the back ordered quantities for this branch for this item. Which is 21. And compare each total for that same item per branch. So we get 3, 0, 4, 21. Then, I want to see which branch had the most items. In this case, Branch 4. Hence 21 items. Where did you get 25?

Comment: @Uueerdo thanks, I will try something else :)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12c+, you can do:

```
SELECT BRANCH, ITEM, MAX(QTY) AS LEQTY
FROM ((SELECT BRANCH, ITEM, SUM(QTY) AS LEQTY
       FROM TABLE1
       GROUP BY BRANCH, ITEM
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT BRANCH, ITEM, SUM(QTY) AS LEQTY
       FROM TABLE2
       GROUP BY BRANCH, ITEM
      )
     ) bi
WHERE ITEM = 'XYZ'
GROUP BY BRANCH, ITEM
ORDER BY MAX(QTY) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

In earlier versions:

```
SELECT BRANCH, ITEM, LEQTY
FROM (SELECT BRANCH, ITEM, MAX(QTY) AS LEQTY, rownum as rn
      FROM ((SELECT BRANCH, ITEM, SUM(QTY) AS LEQTY
             FROM TABLE1
             GROUP BY BRANCH, ITEM
            ) UNION ALL
            (SELECT BRANCH, ITEM, SUM(QTY) AS LEQTY
             FROM TABLE2
             GROUP BY BRANCH, ITEM
            )
           ) bi
      WHERE ITEM = 'XYZ'
      GROUP BY BRANCH, ITEM
      ORDER BY MAX(QTY) DESC
     ) bi
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: For newer version, I get ORA-00933. Try to play with () and then ORA-00903.
For earlier versions solution, I get ORA-00935 or ORA-00904

Comment: So based on -> ' select * from v$version '
I am running an erlier version 11.2

Comment: @katjua . . . I see nothing wrong in the first query.  What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinhoff I'm  using 11.2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was able to make it work with this

```
SELECT
    branch, item, BO_qty
FROM
    (SELECT
        branch, item, SUM(BO_qty) AS sum_bo
     FROM
        (SELECT
            branch, item, SUM(BO_qty) AS sum_bo
         FROM
            t1
         GROUP BY
            branch, item
        UNION ALL
         SELECT
            branch, item, SUM(BO_qty) AS sum_bo
         FROM 
            t2
         GROUP BY
            branch, item
        )
     GROUP BY
        branch,
        item
     ORDER BY
        BO_qty DESC
    )
WHERE
    ROWNUM=1
```

It returns

```
BRANCH   ITEM    QTY
------   ----    ---
BRANCH4  XYZ     21
```

Comment: I think this is essentially the second query in my answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes you are right. Except I had to take out the MAX in the end, as it was causing trouble. You put me on the right track so thank you :)